# Angular http.post not sending data with subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, http, observable

I am trying to post data to my api. The post.subscribe does not send any data, no error is being thrown. The API is 100% working.
Here is my code:
httpservice.ts

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Product } from './Product';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class HttpService {

  baseURL = 'https://localhost:2403/testapi/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.products = new Array();
  }
  products: Product[];
  post(product: Product): boolean {
    if ( !this.checkIfProductExistsAlready(product) ) {
      console.log('posting product');

      this.http.post<any>(baseURL,{"product": product.name, "price": 10, "done": false})
        .subscribe((data) => {
          console.log(data);
          product.id = data.id;
          console.log('hi');
        },
        error => console.log('uojdsigdk' + error)
      );
      console.log('posted ' + product.id);
      this.products.push(product);
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

form.component.ts

```
addItem(): void {

    this.isError = false;
    if (!this.httpservice.post(new Product(-1, this.name, this.price, 0))) {
      this.isError = true;
    }
}
```

This is the provider declaration in the app.module.ts

```
[...]
  providers: [HttpService],
[...]
```

Is it possible that this is caused by a config file?

Comment: What does the network tab of your developer console say?

Comment: Could you provide some more context? Are you saying the data is not being sent to your back end?

Comment: Your service gets provided twice. If you want a singleton service just provide it like this: "@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})" and delete this: "providers: [HttpService]"
https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this happens because you try to access the local webserver over http**s**?

```
baseURL = 'https://localhost:2403/testapi/';
```

Otherwise use fiddler, do a post request on your api and look what the server is returning. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think `baseURL` is undefined inside your function scope. Try `this.baseURL` instead. Also make sure your local webserver is serving HTTPS, as mentioned before

`this.http.post<any>(baseURL, product);`

becomes

`this.http.post<any>(this.baseURL, product);`

On a side node, a couple of things are potentially wrong with your `Observable` code, as well as the way you are injecting your Service in your app, as has been mentioned in comments.

Answer (score 0):

add response type

```
addItem(): void {    
    this.isError = false;
    if (!this.httpservice.post(new Product(-1, this.name, this.price, 0), { observe: 'response',responseType: 'text' })) {
      this.isError = true;
    }
}
```